# What is the spring method query for IN expression?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

If I have a query like this,

```
SELECT * FROM COMPANIES WHERE COMPANY_ADDRESS IN ('Texas', 'California');
```

How can I convert this into a spring method name query instead of using `@Query`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query method for your case would be:

```
List<Company> findAllByCompanyAddressIn(List<String> addresses);
```

If the `COMPANY_ADDRESS` column corresponds to `companyAddress` entity field.

Comment: For reference: [Spring Data JPA documentation: Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).